# call method overrided in scala

Tags: scala, overriding

Why the folowing code print the string in the override method instead of the original method which should print "test"? I already use parent to point to self and use parent to call the method

```
class myClass {
    parent=>
    def method(a:Int):String={
       "test"
    } 
    def run={
        println(parent.method(1))
    }
}   

val testClass=new myClass {
     override def method(a:Int):String={
          "substring"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the `parent` identifier is simply another name for the `this` object, a pointer to whatever this object is at runtime.
In Scala and Java (on the JVM in general), the rules of invoking a method on an object are that the overridden method of the runtime type of the object is called.
To do this, the JVM relies on [virtual function tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) that associate the object type and the name of a method with its specific implementation.
This is unlike C++, where calling a method on an object value (not pointer or reference) will resolve the method from the compile-time type of that object.

For example, in Scala you could do:

```
val compileTimeVar: myClass = new myClass { override def method(a: Int) = "substring" }
```

From the standpoint of the Scala compiler, `compileTimeVar` has a type `myClass`.
However, the runtime type is the unnamed type internally represented as something like `xxx$anon$1`, and this unnamed type overrides `method`.
Calling:

```
compileTimeVar.method
```

always calls the overridden method if it exists in that runtime type - it will return `"substring"`.

The so-called `self` pointer is no different from assigning the object to a variable with lost runtime type information - your code is equivalent to this:

```
class myClass {
  def parent: myClass = this
  def method(a: Int) = "test"
  def run = println(parent.method(1))
}
```

If you really want `run` to call the `method` defined in `myClass` and not whatever is overridden, do this:

```
class myClass {
  private def privateMethod(a: Int) = "test"
  def method(a: Int) = privateMethod(a)
  def run = println(this.privateMethod(1))
}
```